# Babel compiles constant to undefined

Tags: javascript, babeljs

With this code

```
const noCurrencies: Map<CurrencyCode, Currency> = new Map();

/**
 * Reducer for the finished currency request.
 */
export function currencies(state: Map<CurrencyCode, Currency> = noCurrencies, action: Action): Map<CurrencyCode, Currency> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENCIES:
      return action.currencies;

    default:
      console.log('currencies(reducer): noCurrencies', noCurrencies)
      return state;
  }
}
```

I get this console output:

```
currencies(reducer): noCurrencies undefined
```

Is this a known problem with Babel? How do I debug it? I have a feeling that it's due to this particular file having been called twice during initialisation and thus having a circular dependency with another file.

(I'm not 'recreating a repro from scratch', so don't suggest that, and the types are https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed which get removed in a pre-processor step, and I've tried without types as well, with the same result)

Comment: Look at the transpiler output to debug it.

Comment: Any chance you call the function before the `const` is initialised? (Babel doesn't implement the TDZ)

Comment: Yes, a circular dependency (although not exactly leading to a double initialisation) would have exactly that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was a large circular dependency between modules. Even if using ECMAScript module syntax, the compiler (WebPack 3 + babel) is not smart enough to only load what is needed when it's needed; but instead evaluate *all* exports and imports whenever a file is used/touched.

That means that if you have `index.js` files that liberally export things from around them, to create a single entry-point for callers outside its folder, you'll likely run into issues like this.

I had to go through the code-base and make the imports 'deep' by directing imports straight to the, of the index file, surrounding files, instead.

E.g.

- folder A

  - epics.js
  - commands.js
  - index.js
  - types.js
  - actions.js
  - reducers.js
  - messages.js
  - ...
- folder B

  - `import { create } from '../A'` becomes `import { create } from '../A/types'`
  - and so forth for all things; in the end I'm only exporting React views and types from `index.js`